# Why is it possible to access vectors created inside a for loop that are saved to a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, scope, std

I've been experimenting with the vector container of C++ and noticed that when I use a vector of vectors and create and push back a vector to it inside a for-loop, I am still able to access these vectors created inside the for-loop.

I've tried to google it but only encountered mentions of move operation in C++ which I don't quite understand. As a C programmer, I expected a segmentation fault when I tried to access the vectors, that are created on the stack, outside the scope of the for loop in the code below. Can someone explain to me what C++ is doing in the background here? How is this possible?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void display (const vector<vector<int> >& tdv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tdv.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <tdv[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << " " << tdv[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main () {
    vector<vector<int> > vov;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        vector<int> vec(i, i);
        vov.push_back(vec);
    }
    display (vov);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get the output below:

```
 1
 2 2
 3 3 3
 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: *As a C programmer, I expected a segmentation fault when I tried to access the vectors* -- So as a `C` programmer, were you aware that you can return and pass a `struct` by value with no issues in `C`?  This is the same concept, just that C++ extends it to other types by using the concept of constructors and destructors.

Comment: As any type of programmer never expect a segfault. It's a sucker bet sometimes a bad pointer points to valid memory and you do not get a segfault. The system may not have reclaimed the memory used by the bad pointer and there will be no segfault. Sometimes the memory was quickly reused by some other part of the the same program and you don't get a segfault. There are many reasons why you might not get a segfault.

Comment: Segfaults suck when you aren't expecting them, but they beat the hell out of not getting the segfault and the code trampling all over valid memory owned by some other part of the program or the code writing into memory it used to own for hours, days, or years before something perturbs the system and the program finally does get the segfault. Murphy's law says it will be at a bad time. Like right when the captain turns on the plane's autopilot.

Comment: @user4581301 You are right. I should be more careful about expecting seg-faults. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Vectors do not behave like a reference / pointer / iterator types. They do not refer to objects owned by someone else. They own their own buffer and there are no other owners of that buffer, and they keep that buffer alive for their entire lifetime.

Vector is a value type. When you create a copy of a vector, you get a new dynamic array with copies of the elements. A copy of a vector doesn't refer to the same buffer as the original.

> ```
> vector<int> vec(i, i);
> ```

This is a local variable. The vector allocates a buffer in dynamic memory.

> ```
> vov.push_back(vec);
> ```

This creates a copy the vector object inside the buffer of the vector of vectors. The copy has its own dynamic buffer.

The local variable is destroyed at the end of the iteration, but the copy lives on in the vector of vectors. And since each vector has their own unique buffer, the buffer of the living vector is unaffected by the other vector being destroyed.

Comment: The clarification about how each vector has its own unique buffer and how they don't act like pointers really helped. I didn't know the local vector was copied into the buffer of the vector of vectors. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

`push_back()` adds a copy of its parameter to the vector.

```
    vector<int> vec(i, i);
    vov.push_back(vec);
```

This creates a temporary `vec` object, yes. It passes a reference to that object to the `push_back()` method, which adds a copy of the object to the vector (reallocating everything in the vector, if necessary).

Afterwards the temporary object is destroyed, but that's ok. A copy of it now exists in the vector.

A vector owns all objects that it contains. Whatever means are used to add something to a vector, the object gets copied/moved/whatever into the vector, and the vector owns it. That's how a vector works.

And when the vector gets destroyed, all objects in the vector gets destroyed with it.

Most introductory C++ books typically have some practice excersizes for implementing vector-like objects, using C-like primitives. Studying those chapters might prove to be informative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It makes sense that the local vectors can be copied/moved. I will definitely check some C++ books to find exercises that will let me implement vector-like objects using C-like primitives :)

Comment: All vectors, local or otherwise, can be copied or moved. Every container in the C++ library implements a copy/move operation that copies/moves the contents of the container, along with it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik To be more precise: const vectors cannot be moved, and vectors containing non-copyable elements cannot be copied.

Answer (score -1):

The space for a vector is allocated on the heap, not on the stack.  The vector constructor allocates the space, and the vector destructor frees it.

This is standard in C++.  Constructors and Destructors give you a lot of power.